# Contour plot from csv file with row being axis

Tags: python, csv, contour, yaxis

I am trying to make a contour plot from a csv file. I would like the first column to be the x axis, the first row (with has values) to be the y, and then the rest of the matrix is what should be contoured, see the basic example in the figure below.

[Simple table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmwhD.png)

What I am really struggling is to get that first row to be the y axis, and then how to define that set of values so that they can be called into the contourf function. Any help would be very much appreciated as I am very new to python and am really don't know where to start with this problem.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from csv import reader
from matplotlib import cm


f = pd.read_csv('/trialforplot.csv',dayfirst=True,index_col=0)

x = f.head()
y = f.columns
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
z=(x,y)
z=np.array(z)
Z=z.reshape((len(x),len(y)))

plt.contour(Y,X,Z)
plt.colorbar=() 
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylable('Particle Size')
plt.show()
```

I'm stuck at defining the z values and getting my contour plot plotting.

Comment: Please post a simple version of your code that shows how far you've gotten and explain where you are getting stuck.

Comment: @Craig done! :)